# region error thrown while gcloud preview app deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, managed-vm

While trying to deploy a module of a VM instance in us-central1-a, the
:gcloud preview app deploy .yaml

throws an error:
Error:(gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not pick a region and/or zone.

I ve set the region us-central1 in gcloud config list and zone as us-central1-a.Any additional pointers to what can be cause will be very helpful

Comment: Have you tried this without region/zone set in `gcloud config`? Do you get the same outcome?

Comment: Yes.Initially there was no region or zone set.Then tried explicitly setting the region and zone in config but that too doesn't help

Comment: That's unexpected. Can you post the logs (should be in a location shown by `gcloud info`) in a gist/pastebin (after removing any personal information)?

Comment: Please try disabling and re-enabling the Google Compute Engine API in the [Cloud Console](http://cloud.google.com/console) (APIs -> Compute Engine API). If that doesn't work, please send me your Google Cloud Platform project number ("Home" in the Cloud Console).

Comment: I'm having the very same issue. Did you solve it by any chance?